# CSS background repeat-x spacing

Tags: css, css-transitions

Thanks for looking at my question! Hopefully somebody can help! :)

Basically I'm trying to use CSS3 (because I'm being lazy and can't be bothered to work it out in Javascript!) to animate a background on a button exactly like the "Buy Tickets Now" button about 800px down on the right on this website's homepage. http://festivalofeducation2013.org.uk/

I'm 90% sure you can do this, but if i'm being silly please just say!

Also, if any of you know and can tell me a simple way to do this with Javascript/jQuery then please feel free! I need to do this anyway possible!

Thanks again in advance.

Comment: rather than link to your website, you should really include code snippits and isolate your issue within a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/BzXSf/1/

**CSS**

```
a.fancy {
    ...
    background: #ccc url(http://colourlovers.com.s3.amazonaws.com/images/patterns/3591/3591132.png?1367352237) 0 0;
    -webkit-transition: background-position 1s;
    -moz-transition: background-position 1s;
    -o-transition: background-position 1s;
    -ms-transition: background-position 1s;
    transition: background-position 1s;
}

a.fancy:hover {
    background-position: 0 -100px;
}
```